# count cases in python

Tags: python, count

If I have a table like

```
ID     Date     Disease    
1      03.07    A   
1      03.07    B
1      03.09    A
1      03.09    C
1      03.10    D
```

I wrote a code like:

```
def combination(listData):
    comListData = [];
    for datum in listData :
            start = listData.index(datum) + 1
            while start < len(listData) :
                    if datum!=listData[start] :
                            comStr = datum+':'+listData[start]
                            if not comStr in comListData :
                                    comListData.append(comStr)
                    start+=1;
    return comListData

def insertToDic(dic,comSick):
    for datum in comSick :
            if dic.has_key(datum) :
                    dic[datum]+=1
            else :
                    dic[datum] = 1

try:
    con = mdb.connect('blahblah','blah','blah','blah')
    cur = con.cursor()
    sql ="select * from table"
    cur.execute(sql);
    data = cur.fetchall();
    start = 0
    end = 1
    sick = []
    dic = {}
    for datum in data :
            end = datum[0]
            if end!=start:
                    start = end
                    comSick = combination(sick)
                    insertToDic(dic,comSick)
                    sick = []
            sick.append(datum[2])
    start = end
    comSick = combination(sick)
    insertToDic(dic,comSick)
    for k,v in dic.items():
            a,b = k.split(':')
            print >>f, a.ljust(0), b.ljust(0), v
    f.close()
```

then I got:

```
From    To     Count
A       B      1
A       A      1
A       C      1
A       D      1

B       A      1
B       C      1
B       D      1

A       C      1
A       D      1

C       D      1
```

and the final version table I got is (In same ID, same direction such as A --> C count as 1 not 2. Same diseases like A --> A doesn't count. A --> B is different with B --> A)

```
From    To     Count
A       B      1
A       C      1
A       D      1

B       A      1
B       C      1
B       D      1

C       D      1
```

but what I want is (excluding same date cases version):

```
From    To     Count
A       A      1
A       C      1
A       D      1

B       A      1
B       C      1
B       D      1

A       D      1

C       D      1
```

and finally

```
From    To     Count
A       C      1
A       D      1

B       A      1
B       C      1
B       D      1

C       D      1
```

which part of my code should I edit?

Comment: Assuming in your 3rd table, From A To A should be From A To B? And if not why From A To B is removed? If yes, should that one also be included in last one?

Comment: @Lafexlos I excluded From A To B because they are on the same date.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I missed this line "`but what I want is (excluding same date cases version):`

Comment: A comment on my answer pointed out that same direction count as 1 even if it appears twice in the same date and ID. Can you clarify as to what the count stands for and give an example where count will be greater than 1 in a result?

Comment: If different ID has same direction, count will be greater than 1 :)

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to rephrase your question. For each `ID` (excluding date to make the problem simpler), you want all possible pairs of values in `Disease` column and how often they occur, in which order of the pair matters. Now, up front there is a builtin function in `Python` that achieve this:

```
from itertools import permutations
all_pairs = permutations(diseases, 2)
```

Given your data, I am guessing it is in csv files. If it is not, please adjust my code yourself (which is kind of trivial Google searches). We will be using the famous library in data-science stacks called `Pandas`. Here is how it goes:

```
from itertools import permutations
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', header=0)
pairs_by_did = df.groupby('ID').apply(lambda grp: pd.Series(list(permutations(grp['Disease'], 2))))
all_pairs = pd.concat([v for i, v in pairs_by_did.iterrows()])
pair_counts = all_pairs.value_counts()
print pair_counts
```

For your example, it prints

```
>>> print pair_counts
(A, B)    2
(D, A)    2
(A, D)    2
(C, A)    2
(B, A)    2
(A, C)    2
(A, A)    2
(C, B)    1
(D, C)    1
(C, D)    1
(D, B)    1
(B, D)    1
(B, C)    1
Name: 1, dtype: int64
```

Now group by `ID` and `date` at the same time, and see what you get.

Comment: What I want isn't all possible pairs of values in Disease column :( it has directionality!

Comment: Based on "same direction such as A --> C count as 1 not 2" you should probably do `permutations(sorted(set(grp['Disease'])), 2)`. Also, the `all_pairs = pd.concat([v for i, v in pairs_by_did.iterrows()])` is unnecessary and even breaks things when there is more than one ID.

Comment: @MartinValgur Thank you for your input. I am then confused why OP has the count if it is not count of occurrence? Also why do we need to sort a `set`, since `set` is unordered?